# MERGE with Oracle Stored Procedure - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, merge

I am trying to insert a records into my table CAT_BOM_ITEM from table TMP_BOM_STEEL8. If there are new records from the source I want the target table to be updated.

I have a procedure created and I am using a merge query inside it.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_LOAD_CAT_BOM_MATERIALS AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM BI_ODS.CAT_BOM_ITEM;

 INSERT INTO BI_ODS.CAT_BOM_ITEM
  (
    ID_BOM_ITEM,
    PT_PART,
    PS_COMP,
    IPD_PART,
    SEPARADOR,
    ORG_ID,
    DB_ID,
    LOADDATE
    )
    SELECT 
    A.ID_SEPARADOR,
    A.PT_PART,
    A.PS_COMP,
    A.IPD_PART,
    A.SEPARADOR,
    A.ORG_ID,
    A.DB_ID,
    A.LOADDATE
    FROM TMP_BOM_STEEL8 A;
    COMMIT;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     '
     Merge Into BI_ODS.CAT_BOM_ITEM B 
      USING
    (SELECT 
    ID_SEPARADOR,
    PT_PART,
    PS_COMP,
    IPD_PART,
    SEPARADOR,
    ORG_ID,
    DB_ID,
    LOADDATE
    FROM TMP_BOM_STEEL8 ) A 
    
   ON (A.ID_SEPARADOR = B.ID_BOM_ITEM
   AND A.DB_ID = B.DB_ID
   AND A.ORG_ID = B.ORG_ID)
   
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
    A.PT_PART = B.PT_PART
    A.PS_COMP= B.PS_COMP
    A.IPD_PART= B.IPD_PART
   A.SEPARADOR = B.SEPARADOR
   
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    ID_SEPARADOR,
    PT_PART,
    PS_COMP,
    IPD_PART,
    SEPARADOR,
    ORG_ID,
    DB_ID,
    LOADDATE) 
    VALUES ( 
    A.ID_SEPARADOR,
    A.PT_PART,
    A.PS_COMP,
    A.IPD_PART,
    A.SEPARADOR,
    A.ORG_ID,
    A.DB_ID,
    A.LOADDATE);
   ';
   
   COMMIT;
```

When i compile the procedure this is the error:

1. ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
2. ORA-06512: at "BI_ODS.SP_LOAD_CAT_BOM_MATERIALS", line 28
3. ORA-06512: at line 2

Can someone help in solving this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `;` semi-colon from the end of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` SQL string. But, I'm not sure why you are using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as it doesn't look like you are using any dynamic SQL and could just use `MERGE` directly in the procedure.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit as it fixed many of the errors in your code and invalidates the existing answers; if you want to add changes then append them rather than overwriting the existing code (or ask a new question).

Comment: Thank you MT10 for your help and feedback. I'm still learning to use the platform now I have in mind that for next posts. Greetings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

- Remove the `;` semi-colon from the end of the string you are passing to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`;
- Add commas at the end of each assignment in the `UPDATE` clause of the `MERGE` statement;
- Swap the left- and right-terms in the `UPDATE` assignments as you are updating `B` from `A` (rather than vice versa);
- Change `INSERT ( ID_SEPARADOR,` to `INSERT ( ID_BOM_ITEM,`; and
- Add `END;` to terminate the stored procedure.

You also don't need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and you shouldn't `COMMIT` in a stored procedure (as it prevents you from being able to `ROLLBACK` multiple statements; instead, use `COMMIT` in the PL/SQL block you are using to call the procedure that way you can control when the `COMMIT` occurs and can chain several procedures together and potentially roll them all back if needed).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=06da783cb334ccce08facc42c798aefb)*

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `END` statement at the end of your procedure, but I don't see anything else particularly wrong. You don't need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and that seems to be the line it's objecting to, so try removing that.